# Reduce array to tuple of first and last element?

Tags: arrays, swift, reduce

I have an array that I would like to first sort, then return the first and last element of the sorted array. I thought I can use `reduce`, but what if I don't have an initial value?

Here is the array I'm trying to work with:

```
let myNumbers = [4, 9, 6, 2, 3]
```

How can `map` this to the first and last of the sorted array to this?:

```
(2, 9)
```

Comment: `map` can't be used. The output of `map` is always an array with the same number of elements as the input. You can't get it to emit a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1: `min()`/`max()`

This is the easiest way:

```
let input = [4, 9, 6, 2, 3]
let output = (input.min(), input.max())
print(output) //(Optional(2), Optional(9))
```

If you're certain that the array isn't empty, you can safely force unwrap the optionals:

```
let input = [4, 9, 6, 2, 3]
let output = (input.min()!, input.max()!) // (2, 9)
```

This is approach does 2 iterations over the array. It's `O(N)`. Unless a sorted list is required elsewhere, sorting then taking the first/last would be worse, as it would be `O(N * log_2(N))`.

## Method 2: `reduce()`

If you insist on using reduce, you can do it like this:

```
let input = [4, 9, 6, 2, 3]
let output = input.reduce((min: Int.max, max: Int.min)){
    (min($0.min, $1), max($0.max , $1))
} //(2, 9)
```

Each reduce iteration sets the accumulator to the new min (the smaller of the old min and current element), and the new max (the larger of the old max and the current).

The initial values of the accumulator are set such that:

- Any element in the array compares as smaller than the accumulator's min
- Any element in the array compares as larger than the accumulator's max

Comment: Using min/max instead of sorting does O(n) times 2, instead of once by sorting once and using first/last, right? (in case this is an array of 10K+)

Comment: Yes, 2 passes. For 10K elements that's 20K iterations. Sorting would take ~132K

Comment: The reduce solution does a single pass, but it's also a more expensive operation (due to closure overhead)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an initialValue for reduce, it's optional.

```
var foo = [1, 40, 20, -20, 50];
var reducer = function(prev, curr, i, arr){return [prev[0] <= curr ? prev[0] : curr, prev[1] >= curr ? prev[1] : curr]};
var baz = foo.reduce(reducer); // [-20, 50]
```

Or maybe like this:

```
var foo = [1, 40, 20, -20, 50];
var reducer = function(prev, curr, i, arr){return {min: prev.min <= curr ? prev.min : curr, max: prev.max >= curr ? prev.max : curr}};
var baz = foo.reduce(reducer); // {min: -20, max: 50}
```

Edit: Just noticed this is for swift and not javascript, whoops lol. I must have been surfing the wrong SO category. I think the principle would be the same in swift except you probably do need to provide some kind of initial value.